# How to send message using Bale bot into group?

Tags: node.js, bale-messenger, balebot

How to send message using Bale bot into group?

for send message using BaleBot, we need to have id of User/Group and have an accessHash. But I can`t get accessHash for send mesage to Group.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not too hard, if you have id and access_hash of the group(or channel). you should just make the Peer and after that put it in send_message function.
look at this code. It push a "Hello" to a specified channel after getting start by client.
Note: Remember group and channel are similar.

```
const SDK = require("balebot");
const BaleBot = SDK.BaleBot;
const TextMessage = SDK.TextMessage;
const Group = SDK.Group;


let bot = new BaleBot('token');


bot.hears(["/start"], (message, responder) => {
   console.log(responder._peer)
    bot.send(new TextMessage("hello"),responder.peer).then((res) => {
        console.log(res)
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks but i don`t know how to get access hash of Group!

Comment: you need to add bot to a group first. after that give the permission to it. it will be able to get updates from the group.

Comment: @Zaaferani thanks for your questions in stackoverflow about bale bot